# Why after docker reboot data is lost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have next `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - my-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

volumes:
  my-mysql-data:
```

When I restart my host system, the data inside database is flushed.

What did I miss at my configuration file?
And where on host this directory is mounted?

Comment: Its a [named/managed volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes), you can see where exaclty it lives on the host system by inspecting it `docker volume inspect compose_project_name_my-mysql-data`.  If you are not sure about the name, do a `docker volume ls` first to know the name. Also note that using :cached for such a data volume isn't a good option. :delegated makes more sense, if you can live with the [potential consequences](https://tkacz.pro/docker-volumes-cached-vs-delegated/).

Answer (score 0):

You are saving cached data. You should use `/var/lib/mysql` path in the volumes

Comment: this cached has a different meaning afaik. It has to do with who sees the updates first, but its not something like in memory only caching like you describe here.